# Red Hat Booth Ticket Issue

Tags: redhat, centos7, high-availability

I am following [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_configuring-multisite-cluster-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters) to implement booth ticket. I have two clusters with 2 nodes in each and 1 arbitrator node on centos 7 hosted on google vm.

The prerequisite for having booth ticket is both cluster should have separate floating Ip.

Here is the command I executed from [this doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_configuring-cluster-resources-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters).

```
pcs resource create VirtualIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.11.100 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s
```

However, pcs is throwing error while executing below command.

```
pcs booth create ip 192.168.11.100
```

Error:

> Error: Value '192.168.11.100' of option 'ip' is not unique across 'ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2' resources. Following resources are configured with the same value of the instance attribute: 'VirtualIP', use --force to override

Tried with `--force` but same error.

I know its throwing error because its already defined as resource.
However, question is how to make it work, either by not having internal floating ip? or there is some work around to this problem?

I have tried with automatically assigned IP address at eth0 (just to make basic ticket feature working) But it seems it doesn't like that and fails on last step of `pcs booth ticket grant apacheticket`.

Any help will be appreciated.